# Problem with using react-i18next and mui/material in a package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-i18next, nx-monorepo

I've made an npm package with various components as a personal project. There is a problem with one of the components in my package, which is basically an mui/Autocomplete component which I've specified some of its props for. some of these props includes direction which is taken from react-i18next package. Something like this:

import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete"
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

const { t, i18n } = useTranslation()

```
<Autocomplete 
        componentsProps={{
            paper: {
                sx: {
                    width: { width },
                    maxWidth: '90vw',
                     direction: i18n.dir(),
                    position: "absolute",
                    fontSize: { fontSize },
                     right: i18n.dir() === "rtl" ? "0" : "unset"
                }
            }
        }}
        .
        .
        .
       noOptionsText={t("اطلاعات یافت نشد")}
    />
```

basically, I am trying to use t and i18n here. the problem is that t and i18n both become undefined when used in an nx monorepo with react. I am using nx because I am trying to make a microUI pattern.
I also get a warning :
react-i18next:: You will need to pass in an i18next instance by using initReactI18next

this is while I have already initialized react-i18next, and the whole thing had no problems before moving to nx.

The package I made (just in case) is named react-input-grid, which has problems when using the GHAutocomplete tag I made.

I have tried removing i18n and and t from the components which use mui, but then I'd have to manually pass them to the component which isn't exactly a very pleasant situation. the problem is just from when I try to use the "useTranslation" hook's functions in mui components.